# SoundCloud API login opens itunes app on IOS 6.0 device?

Tags: ios, soundcloud

Have implemented SoundCloud API into app. All working well, using the SoundCloud IOS Quick Start guide.

```
- (IBAction) login:(id) sender
{
    SCLoginViewControllerCompletionHandler handler = ^(NSError *error) {
    if (SC_CANCELED(error)) {
        NSLog(@"Canceled!");
    } else if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Done!");
    }
};

[SCSoundCloud requestAccessWithPreparedAuthorizationURLHandler:^(NSURL *preparedURL) {
    SCLoginViewController *loginViewController;

    loginViewController = [SCLoginViewController
                           loginViewControllerWithPreparedURL:preparedURL
                                            completionHandler:handler];
    [self presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
}];
}
```

However, when I test on device iPhone IOS 6.0 - and try and login in - the SoundCloud screen appears, I add my details, but when I click connect [to SoundCloud], the iTunes player opens and my app closes. (Which is annoying) I can reopen my app and am logged into SoundCloud. Why would iTunes open? When I am logging into SoundCloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you define as your `URL-Scheme` in `YourApplication-Info.plist`?

Please note that it needs to match what you have assigned as the `Redirect URI` param at `https://soundcloud.com/you/apps/`.

For more information about custom URL schemes check [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

#### Registering Custom URL Schemes

`"To register a URL type for your app, include the CFBundleURLTypes key in your app’s Info.plist file. The CFBundleURLTypes key contains an array of dictionaries, each of which defines a URL scheme the app supports.
"`

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Many thanks - still not working. May have wired up plist incorrectly. Under URL types have URL identifier as com.mydomain.myapp.soundcloud and URL Schemes as Music://oauth which is the same as Redirect URI. Used temp name for bundle display name - just to check new plist file is loaded on device. But still the iTunes player opens when I press the Soundclound connect button. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Working - changed the URI param from Music://oauth to composer://oauth. Thanks for help.